# Laravel Ajax response post method

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

My code below works when i use the get route.I just want to send data with ajax and then retrieve it back.

```
$('.link').click(function(){
        var c = $(this).text();
        var url = '{{route('home')}}';


        $.ajax({

            url:url,
            data:{'mydata' : c  }

        })
        .done(function(msg){
            console.log(msg['response']);
        });

    });
```

and in my routes file :

```
Route::get('/home', function(Request $request){
return response()->json(['response' => $request['mydata']]);})->name('home');
```

It works fine when i am using get method in Route.When i am using post i get an error : 405 (Method Not Allowed).
I used method:'post' on AJAX and i get an error : 500 (Internal Server Error)

Anyone could help? thank you.

Comment: can you show your post functions?

Comment: You can not POST to a GET route. Define another route, for eg: Route::post('/home', function(Request $request) { //Do something here  });

You can then use type: 'POST' in the AJAX request to make a POST request.

Comment: If you defined get in route, it only allow get method. Same also in Post. If you want to make sure both method work, use **Route::any()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    var c = $(this).text();
    var url = '{{route('home')}}';


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:url,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
        data:{'mydata' : c  }

    })
    .done(function(msg){
        console.log(msg['response']);
    });

});
```

And in routes

```
Route::post(...
```

Comment: as i said when i am using post i get an error  405 (Method Not Allowed).I wrote the code with get because this is the only way its working.

Comment: OK i see...i will update my answer now...You must specify in ajax that it's a post type, because by default it is a get!

Comment: Glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

when you use post, change the route.

```
Route::post('/home',
```